# Failed to build gem native extension when Installing capybara-webkit (0.12.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, capybara-webkit

I can't install the [Capybara Webkit Driver](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) as I receive this error:

```
Installing capybara-webkit (0.12.1) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

I'm running on Windows 7 x64 and as you can see, installed with the RailsInstaller for Windows. I tried `gem install capybara-webkit` and right now I have it in my gem file but both return the same error.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You also need to install QT 4.7.x OpenSource edition (with support for
>   mingw32) AND add Qt's bin directory to path.

This is from [official wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit) in windows section. So you probably need to install damn thing. Can't provide anything more detailed since I'm not using windows for RoR(and suggesting you the same).